# WPF how to include resource

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So as I was reading how to use a MVVM design in my project looking into a sample-MVVM-concept project I found this:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDemo.UserRegistrationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
```

I create a new project add this:

```
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and "DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"" to the Grid clause.

But I get strange errors. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you maybe share us the strange errors what you've got?

Comment: what is that strange errors??